# Verify git connection with credentials

Tags: git, github

In code I need to verify if connection to github or another git repo for a particular user will work.

I can do it using `ls-remotes` but, unfortunately,  ls-remotes doesn't require credentials to be used. With github it works without specifying any credentials.

Is it possible to verify whether "push" operation will be successful for a particular user + password without actually doing real clone -> push?

Many thanks

Comment: Even if you can successfully talk to the server, your push operation may fail because of server-side hooks. These won't be possible to verify until you actually try to push.

Comment: You can [check if a user is a collaborator](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#check-if-a-user-is-a-collaborator) using Github API. You can check for [user's permission level](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#review-a-users-permission-level).